# Multiple Firebase Functions not working

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I tried using multiple Cloud Functions to be fired when certain events are created. They both write to different positions of the Firebase database. But how do I specify which Cloud Functions will be fired and then retrieve certain data that would be written to the database?

Below is my code.

**My JS**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/{Systems_Devt}/{Systems_DevtId}/name')
.onWrite(( change,context) =>{

// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
var str1 = "Lecture material uploaded: " + eventSnapshot;
console.log(eventSnapshot);

var topic = "Management.Information.System";
var payload = {
    data: {
        name: str1,
    }
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
    .then(function (response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
});

exports.sendNotification1 = functions.database.ref('/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/{Enterprise_Sys}/{Enterprise_SysId}/name')
.onWrite(( change,context) =>{

// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
var str1 = "Lecture material uploaded: " + eventSnapshot;
console.log(eventSnapshot);

var topic = "Management.Information.System";
var payload = {
    data: {
        name1: str1,
    }
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
    .then(function (response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
});
```

**My onMessage Recieved**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("name"));
        showNotification1(remoteMessage.getData().get("name1"));
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

    }
}

private void showNotification1(String name1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Lecture Notes(Enterprise Systems)")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText(name1)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private void showNotification(String name) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Lecture Notes(System Dev't)")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText(name)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

**What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Cloud Functions, triggering on these two paths:

```
/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/{Systems_Devt}/{Systems_DevtId}/name
/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/{Enterprise_Sys}/{Enterprise_SysId}/name
```

Each of the segments wrapped in `{}` defines a variable. If you remove the variable names, both of theses are `/Lecture_Materials/*/*/*/name`. This means that as far as Cloud Functions are concerned these are these functions trigger on the same path.

If you want to make each function trigger for a different operation, you need to ensure that the path is unique. A typical approach would be to use paths like this:

```
/Lecture_Materials/Systems_Devt/{MIS}/{Systems_Devt}/{Systems_DevtId}/name
/Lecture_Materials/Enterprise_Sys/{MIS}/{Enterprise_Sys}/{Enterprise_SysId}/name
```

If the `{Systems_Devt}` and your current paths are not actually wildcards, but meant to be literal strings, you can also keep your current paths and remove those `{}`:

```
/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/Systems_Devt/{Systems_DevtId}/name
/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/Enterprise_Sys/{Enterprise_SysId}/name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. What about my OnMessageReceived class? Is it correct?